# Fixing First Column and Header HTML Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a this table:

```
`https://jsbin.com/hutifufisa/edit?html,css,js,output`
```

And I already fixed the first column using an example i saw here in stack, but if the table contains a lot of values and being responsive, it's not easy to know which value i'm checking because the header is not fixed when you scroll down, thinking about mobile UX, im using bootstrap to create the table.

Is it possible to keep the first column fixed, just like it already is, and also fix the header?

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

for responsive table and UI good developers always used bootstrap.
responsive table bootstrap.

read this link https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_tables.asp for read more about responsive table and bootstrap(Bootstrap is so easy just used class and read and research)

Comment: I am already using bootstrap @Team Work. I am trying to also fix the header. check my fiddle plz